# Why does my for loop run indefinitely and doesn't stop when the if condition is met?

Tags: python, loops, file, for-loop, ctf

I'm trying to read text from a file and using a loop to find a specific text from the file. The data in the file is listed vertically word by word.
When I run the script, after it prints the last word in the file it repeats itself from the beginning indefinitely.

```
with open('dictionary.txt','r') as file:
    dictionary = file.read().strip()
for i in dictionary:
 print (dictionary)
 if( i == "ffff" ):
    break
```

Comment: Do you mean to be printing out the whole file for every iterable in the file? Seems like `print(i)` might be what you want instead.

Comment: You are iterating over a string containing all the text in the file and printing whole file for every single character in that string.

Comment: `i` is never going to be anything other than a single character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first split the lines by `"\n"` then `print(i)` not `print(dictionary)`:

```python
with open('dictionary.txt', 'r') as file:
    dictionary = file.read().strip().split("\n")
for i in dictionary:
    print(i)
    if i == "ffff":
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

before, you should `split` the lines b/c it will loop into the string and check if the characters are `ffff`, and it won't be `True`

i will be a single character, so you should do first

```
dictionary = dictionary.split("\n")
```

**BUT** if your `ffff` is a line, if is a word separated with spaces you can do:

```
dictionary = dictionary.split(" ")
```